# $f(x) = \ln x + \int_0^x\sqrt{1+\sin t}\,dt$ function

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on the interval $(0,\infty)$ by 
>   $$f(x) = \ln x + \int_0^x\sqrt{1+\sin t}\,dt.$$
>
> Then prove that there exists $\alpha>1$ such that $|f'(x)| < |f(x)|$ for all $x \in (\alpha,\infty )$

$f(x)$ is increasing as $f'(x)>0$, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x}$, after this step not able to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x\gt1$ we have

$$|f'(x)|=\left|{1\over x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x}\right|={1\over x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x}\lt1+\sqrt2$$

while for $x\gt \alpha=e^{1+\sqrt2}$ we have $\ln x\gt1+\sqrt2$, in which case

$$|f'(x)|\lt1+\sqrt2\lt\ln x\lt \ln x+\int_0^x\sqrt{1+\sin t}dt=f(x)\le|f(x)|$$

Answer (score 0):

Define $g(x)=\frac{|f'(x)|}{|f(x)|}$ and observe that 
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x) = 0.
$$
Therefore, there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that for every $x > \alpha$, we have $g(x) < 1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the 3rd line like how did you get $g(x)<1$ ? .

Comment: I used the definition of limit with $\varepsilon = 1$.